# How to read or convert large .sdf file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, large-data

I'm trying to open and read and possibly convert.sdf file to csv but I don't know any program that does such a thing because the files I have are over 15 Gb. Is there any way I can do it with python or Mathematica or any other windows application?

Comment: In principle you can do this, if you have enough memory and disk space. And if not, you can still do it with Python or Mathematica, by writing the appropriate code that does not try to load the entire file at once.

Comment: Simple Data, Spatial Data… what’s the specific format?